# LAMP server not formatting FROM email address correctly?

Tags: php, email, lamp

I am using the PHP mail() function to send an email from the server.

Recently the emails have been bouncing because google is rejecting emails that do not correctly format email the from address (what the IT guy is telling me).

The from address is coming through as user@server@mydomain.com.
I am specifying the from in the header portion of the mail() function and worked up until a few days ago when they started bouncing(pretty@mydomain.com). All I can figure is that google is distinguishing this address from the real send from address.

Where would I look to change this send from address? Apache? PHP? Other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use headers in the call of mail() to pass the send from address:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have that in place and it was working. However, for some reason google is seeing it as user@server@mydomain.com.  Is there another place in the server configuration where I can change this?

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear what google sees as user@server@mydomain.com. Can you please explain how you got that information from google? How do you know that google thinks the sender is user@server@mydomain.com? In my knowledge the From is a header in the mail request, nothing more. There is though some checks in the DNS that could help out that makes sure that custom email from headers are validated by the reciever (SPF record: see https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en)

Comment: I will troubleshoot a little deeper on Monday. Thank you for the SPF record link; I will look into that.